# Decoding JSON strings containing arrays

Tags: json, swift, macos, decode, encode

I'm encoding and decoding to and from JSON strings using JSONSerialization in the class below. I can encode both NSDictionaries & NSArrays and I can decode strings that have been encoded using NSDictionaries but not strings that were encoded from arrays, it barfs at JSONSerialization.jsonObject( ...
I can work without arrays, at a pinch but it would be nice to know why this is happening. Thoughts appreciated

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]  
let s = JSON.Encode( a )!
JSON.Decode( s ) // fails    

let a = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 ]  
let s = JSON.Encode( a )!
JSON.Decode( s ) // works
```

-

```
class JSON: NSObject {

   static func Encode( _ obj: Any ) -> String? {

       do {
           let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0) )

           if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
               return string as String
           }
           return nil
       } catch let error as NSError {
           return nil
       }
   }

   static func Decode( _ s: String ) -> (NSDictionary?) {

       let data = s.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
       do {
           // fails here to work on anything other than "{ a : b, c : d }"
           // hates any [1,2,3] arrays in the string
           let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
           return json
       } catch let error as NSError {
           return nil
       }

   }   

}
```

Comment: Swift is not Objective-C. Classes don't have to have a base class, so don't inherit from `NSObject` unless you have a good reason to do so and don't use old Foundation types that have native Swift equivalents, such as `NSString`, `NSDictionary` and `NSError`. Moreover why don't you use `JSONEncoder` and `Codable` introduced in Swift 4?

Comment: Mostly because as far as Swift is concerned I'm still a bit green. This was written a while ago when I was in a hurry and I'm just now revisiting to tidy up the mess. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the result to **dictionary** so it cannot work with something else.

A solution is to make the function generic and specify the expected return type.

I cleaned up the code a bit, basically it’s recommended to make a function `throw` if it contains a *throwing* API.

```
class JSON {

    enum JSONError : Error { case typeMismatch }

    static func encode( _ obj: Any ) throws -> String {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }

    static func decode<T>( _ s: String ) throws -> T {
        let data = Data(s.utf8)
        guard let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? T else {
           throw JSONError.typeMismatch 
        }
        return result
    }
}


let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
do {
    let s = try JSON.encode(a)
    let u : [Int] = try JSON.decode(s)
    print(u)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Note (as always):

In Swift do not use `NSDictionary`, `NSString` and `NSError`and `.mutableContainers` is completely pointless.